# How do i retain my unique identifiers when doing a clean and stem using tm package in R?

Tags: r, tm, corpus

```
#to prepare for dataframesource you must change name to doc_id and text.
textdataframe <- textdataframe %>% rename(doc_id= orig_id, text= orig.narr)

corpus=Corpus(DataframeSource(textdataframe))

corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus[[1]][1]  

#remove punctuation
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus[[1]][1]

#remove stopwords
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("cloth", stopwords("english")))
corpus[[1]][1]  

#stemming
corpus = tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus[[1]][1]
```

What ends up happening is i lose my unique id's that i assigned when setting dataframe source. I would like to set it up and continue it to be edited as i go along with clean and stem.

Comment: Run this `meta(corpus, type = "indexed")`, what output you receive?

Comment: data frame with 0 columns and 3702 rows

Comment: When i don't add the dataframesource part it works the way i want it to.

Comment: Even if you add `DataFrameSource` you should still be able to fetch identifiers. Run `inspect(corpus[1:2])` it should return `id` and `text` for first 2 rows.

Comment: yes i was able to fetch two rows, but i have no way of telling the identity of each row.

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in `doc_id` column?

Comment: surprisingly no duplicates.

Comment: Maybe you need to manually keep the ID information and join it again, see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19851799)

Comment: I didn't want to do a join because the point of this is using this as a check against a join.

Comment: Run this `meta(corpus, "id")` after clean and stem step, maybe the IDs are being stored. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516782)

Comment: it gives me the row numbers not the id that i assigned to it. Its like it washes it away once i start the cleaning process.

Comment: It's due to tm_map, a user asked a similar question, see if this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25639656) works.

Comment: That worked. Initially i said it gave me different words, but i recognize its the same just the order changed which is fine.Thank you so much